# Web Form with more than 100 fields

Tags: webforms

What would be the best design layout for a web form with more than 100 fields? Right now I have grouped the fields to tabs.I am having tough time in validating the fields.I should either validate it on 'Submit' of the form or on tab change.Both has its own drawbacks. If I validate on tab change then user cannot view other tabs till they fill all the mandatory fields in the previous tab.Also it is not an good idea to throw so many validation messages to the user when he submits the form.
Please share your thoughts..

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ***stepwise process***. In the first step provide all the most important fields. Then on the click of a 'Next' button you can go to the next step and so on. By validating the fields you can allow the user to go to the next step.

Comment: yes rahul is right. And by the way Akash the tab way is the wrong way u r going.